# Woocommerce Single Product: Hide option if product has size x

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I am searching for the code, to solve this problem in woocommerce:
+ If my product has the size 90-140, it has 1 firmness to choose
+ If my product has the size 160-200, it has 2 firmnesses to choose

Or with other words:
IF "size" = 90, 100, 120, 140
THEN hide "firmness 2"

It should also be disabled in the card

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The idea is to try it yourself, post your code, and if it still does not work (after debugging) ... then ask a question.

Comment: first check in DB if product size is record somewhere if is pull data for current product and check if() ....